# Firebase Storage Nodejs How I can show url Public PDF Files in the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload files from firebase storage for now they seem to upload correctly, except that it doesn't provide me with a public url from firebase console and I can't see the information I'm hosting.

[image]

I'm using the api of firebase-admin to upload the files

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(...)
let storage = admin.storage().bucket();

const options = {        
     public:true,
     destination:`invoices/${clientNum}/invoice-${invoiceabs}.pdf`
};

let storageRef = await storage.upload(invoicePath,options)
```

What can I do?

Thank you

Comment: Download URLs in the console are **only** created by a client app when it uploads a file to the storage bucket using the Firebase client SDK, then requests a download URL using the client SDK's API.  You can't create that specific type of Firebase download URL from your backend.  You can create other types of download URLs as described in the duplicate, but they won't be linked in the console.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you very much.